# xcode 6.1 installation process

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite, xcode6.1-gm-seed

I installed Yosemite a couple of days ago. It really broke quite a lot of things - broke my favorite game which won't start, broke my php installation, my wordpress installation, and now Homebrew! But the spotlight feature is nice, not that it makes up for it lol.

Nonetheless I'm trying to fix Homebrew which is telling me to update to XCode 6.1. I've run software update and it says the XCode 6.1 has been installed (sort of). It has:

Command Line Tools (OSX 10.10) - Version 6.1 Installed Oct 17, 2014 (twice actually)
Xcode Version 6.0.1 - Installed Oct 17, 2014

And no pending updates.

But when I check the locations tab in Xcode preferences - it says it's using Command Line Tools 6.0.1. And when I run brew doctor it tells me to upgrade to 6.1 CLT.

How do I update the CLT to 6.1? (note I'm not on Apple Developer program)

Comment: Oh that's a worry, so my homebrew is broken until they release XCode 6.1?

Comment: I found this link  on another forum https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_6.1/xcode_6.1.dmg It works with my normal apple id - so downloading now, another 2.5GB! will update tomorrow if it works.

Comment: Ah, good, I saw that link but since it's under "developer" I assumed it wasn't publicly available.

Comment: I think I did sign up for the IOS developer awhile back, but I haven't paid for a long time, maybe I still have access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link that @richard-g provided doesn't seem to work anymore, but I just found the dmg file on

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

using an appleID that has only a free developer login.

On that page I found both Xcode 6.1 and the command line tools for OS X 10.10 for Xcode 6.1.

Before finding that, on the first machine that I upgraded from Maverick to Yosemite that already had Xcode installed on it, I was able to upgrade Xcode in the App Store and then run Xcode and from within it download and upgrade the command line tools, but App Store continues to show Xcode as one update available with just an "Open" button. I'll see if installing the downloaded dmg takes care of that, and in any case I have other machines to upgrade and could use the offline install package. The download site seems very very slow, though, the 2.5GB download is taking all day.

Answer (score 1):

It worked - installing the 6.1 XCode from this download https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_6.1/xcode_6.1.dmg
and it worked fine. I just had to go to Xcode -> Locations and select the 6.1 CLT, then open a new command prompt.

brew doctor

Your system is ready to brew.

========================================================

Sorry as per comments - the link to XCode is no longer working

Comment: No such luck for me.  I had a registered Apple ID and logged in with that, then registered my normal Apple ID -- in both cases, when I got to the XCode 6.1 download in the developer center download page, get an Access Denied message.  I also tried this after unsuccessfully attempting to install the update to 6.1 offered via the App Store updater -- it seemed to work, but XCode crashes and still reports being older 6.01.

Comment: Oh ok, yeah now when I try that link it is giving me an Access Denied error page. But I can't see the update in the App Store though either, maybe they've released it to some countries and discontinued that link or somethings... if anyone knows the new way to get XCode 6.1, please post here...

Comment: I posted a request to Apple Dev support, and (despite providing a great deal of information in the request) they asked me to provide information about the problem so they could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

As you have Xcode 6.1 installed, you can run `xcode-select --install` from a shell to download the correct CLT.

Answer (score 0):

This link works without without requiring login:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action